# Jenkins - Restrict project rights for administrator

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My plan was to restrict even some admin accounts inside Jenkins. So that it is possible to confige/manage Jenkins global settings but not the configurations of all projects.

For that I tried to give admin accounts only rights to change Jenkins config. Then I created project roles and assigned those roles to specified admins.

Unfortunatly each admin was still able to configure all projects. Any ideas what I must configure to achieve this?

EDIT:
Maybe the image makes things clearer (showing my role strategy plugin configuration)
[image]

I configured it in such a way, that "admin" has none, but the overall  rights. Then I created Job roles again user and admin. There it's allowed to configure jobs. If I make myself overall admin and job user, I can still configure the Job. :(

Comment: Just try this plug-in this might solve your need: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am already using this plugin. I edited my question a little.